# Wix, Windows installer Restart Manager preventing service uninstall?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX-based Windows installer where part of the install is to start a service. This is running on Windows 7, so uses Windows Installer v5.0.

Everything seems to work fine on the install--all files are installed in the correct locations. I have things set up so I can avoid turning the service on (no 'Start' attribute in the ServiceControl tag).  When I rerun the msiexec /i and choose 'Remove' from the modification dialog, however, everything is deleted except the service (in the Service control panel) and the service .exe file, and then the Restart Manager attempts to restart the service!

I've gone through the log for the last three days looking for a solution to why this is happening: why the service .exe is not uninstalled, and why the Restart Manager attempts to restart it, since it was not explicitly excluded. The component containing the service is, for some unknown reason that does not appear in the log, marked as Null for the action to be taken, while every other file in the installation is marked to be removed.

Anybody have any idea if the Restart Manager somehow can interfere with a service being marked for removal during uninstall?  I assume the Restart Manager is trying to restart the service because the component containing it isn't going away, but would like that confirmed or denied, too.

Any help or information would be appreciated!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified to stop the service and remove on uninstall? This is how I setup a service that needs to start in the stopped state and be removed on uninstall:

```
<ServiceControl Id="MyService"
                Name="MyService"
                Stop="both"
                Remove="uninstall" />
```

Comment: Yes, my <ServiceControl> looks very like yours.  The weird part is that I have two products, both built with the wix-maven-plugin and using very similar WiX XML files. Both cause the service to be stopped. The first (broken) one leaves the service installed, and the .exe file present.  The second (working) one uninstalls the service and removes the .exe.  There is no debug info indicating that the service removal failed (the .exe is already marked as null action by the time InstallValidate runs.)  No debug info indicating why this is, of course. (I need a 'trace' level of debug output!)

Comment: One other thing to add--the same .msi that fails to uninstall on Windows 7 uninstalls perfectly on XP. I'm wondering if somehow the Restart Manager is involved, but if so, why does one product uninstall correctly on Windows 7 and another not?